# Splitting string every 80 spaces

Tags: python

I have a string of 6400 numbers which I want to put into an 80x80 string format, for example

```
string1 = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
string2 = '''1 2 3
             4 5 6
             7 8 9'''
```

*the numbers are different lengths too

I have tried using split() but I don't know how to 'count' the amount of spaces and put it into one large string

Comment: `split()` doesn't add newlines, it splits string to lists which is not what is needed here.

Comment: You can use strong slice (:) with for loop. But don't forget strings are immutable. You need to concatenate on new variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split on space and iterate through it making chunks of given size:

```
string1 = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

size = 3
splits = string1.split()

print('\n'.join(' '.join(splits[j] for j in range(i, i+size)) for i in range(0, len(splits), size)))

# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6                                                                                      
# 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Variable-length numbers? Just use regex.

```
import re

string1 = '1 22 333 4444 55555 666666 77777777 888888888 9999999999'
string2 = '\n'.join(re.findall('((?:\S+ ){2}\S+)', string1))
```

The `(?:)` makes a group you can repeat but doesn't capture it in the match, which makes the direct join possible. Without it, you'd get tuples.

A `re.sub` would also work.

```
string2 = re.sub('((\S+ ){2}\S+) ', lambda m: m.group()+'\n', string1)
```

You would use a `{79}` instead of the `{2}` of course, which repeats the `'\S+ '` pattern (one or more non-whitespace characters followed by a space) so you don't have to write it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by slicing the string by a set chunk size

```
# Print a new line every 6 characters
# Change this as needed
chunk_size = 6

# The string to split
s =  '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

# Iterate over a range of numbers 0 to the length of the string
# with a step size of `chunk_size`
# With `chunk_size` as 6, the range will look like
# [0, 6, 12]
for i in range(0, len(s), chunk_size):
    # Slice the string from the current index
    # to the current index plus the chunk size
    # ie: [0:6], [6:12], [12:18]
    print(s[i:i+chunk_size])

print()

# To do this with list comprehension
s2 = "\n".join(s[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(s), chunk_size))
print(s2)

# Ouptut:
# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
# 7 8 9
```

Or if you have variable length numbers, do as Austin said, and apply the same concept on a split version of the string

```
chunk_size = 3
s = '10 20 30 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()

for i in range(0, len(s), chunk_size):
    print(" ".join(s[i:i+chunk_size]))

print()

s2 = "\n".join(" ".join(s[i:i+chunk_size]) for i in range(0, len(s), chunk_size))
print(s2)

# Output:
# 10 20 30
# 4 5 6
# 7 8 9
```

Comment: You should use `split()` or else it fails for multiple digit numbers in string, for eg: 10 11 12.